# imageview clicklistener get nullpointexception and send to parse

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, crash, imageview

from some reason, which I can't understand I run my app, and it crashes.
the LogCat says that it's because nullpointer exception. what is the problem in my code?

This is line 96(which there is the problem(that's what the logcat says):

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

LogCat:

```
    06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nir.rauch.facebook/nir.rauch.facebook.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at nir.rauch.facebook.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:96)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
06-12 23:19:53.916: E/AndroidRuntime(24740):    ... 11 more
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public EditText email;
public EditText password;

public ImageView quest;
public TextView forgotpassword;
public TextView signup;
public ImageView login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // parse things
    Parse.initialize(this, "QQHtKNtHhwv6uzAFvfF1GdvhfaO6Lj39vVcJEE2I",
            "BCZ3Amr10te5ehVsod9iJZ82uWMv2uwRZKFgCMEH");
    // launce
    final Animation slideUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animstart);

    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.facebooklogo);
    img.startAnimation(slideUp);
    // SystemClock.sleep(10000);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.Password);

            email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
            signup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign);
            signup.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Our "
                                    + " try again later.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            login = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.login);

        }
    }, 2500);


    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
            String Email = email.getText().toString();
            String PassWord= password.getText().toString();

            ParseObject FacebookUsers = new ParseObject("User");
                FacebookUsers.put("Mail", Email  );
                FacebookUsers.put("PassWord", PassWord );

                FacebookUsers.saveInBackground();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try putting all your "findViewById"s outside of the Handler/Runnable. Why are you trying to make it wait before setting an OnClickListener to "signup"? In line 96, "login" doesn't exist yet, because you only tell it what "login" is after the Runnable wait time, yes?

Comment: works , great. have some probling with xml because of the imageview size, but I've got it. thanks! @AJMacdonald